# ElasticSearch yields wrong results when using terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of documents indexed on ElasticSearch with the following structure

```
{
  "product_id": "xx",
  "product_desc":"some product desc"
}
```

When I perform a search with term, as follows, I get the correct results:

```
GET my_index/my_doctype/_search
{"query": 
 {
  "match":{"product_id": "138156"}
  }
}
```

However, when I perform the same search with terms, I get a wrong results

```
GET my_index/my_doctype/_search
{
          "query": {
            "terms": {
              "product_id": ["138156"]
        }
  }
}
```

This happens for some products and not all them. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How is the "product_id" field indexed?  What data type is it and is it analyzed or not?

Comment: @RyanWalker Thanks for replying! it's of type string and no analyzer is specified so I assume the default analyzer is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For terms query to work correctly on a string field the field must be non-analyzed.  See for example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Thanks! I can't see the "non-analyzed" requirement anywhere in the link. Anyways, I'll try it. Is it possible to change a field to non-analyzed without having to reindex?

Comment: I think it's the wrong link to the documentation. The correct one is this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: No you have to reindex. Look at Multifields if you need the analyzed and unanalyzed version!